# Python LXML installation issues

Tags: python, lxml

I can't seem to install the lxml package for Python. I'm on a Mac osx 10.14

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-lxml
sudo port install py27-lxml
and pip install lxml
```

and they all output:

`apt-get:command not found, port: command not found, pip:command not found`.

What am I doing wrong? I installed Python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is pip --version giving you?
Try pip3 instead of pip

Such as:

```
pip3 install lxml
```

Comment: When running pip --version. It's saying command not found. but pip3 did the trick! thank you!